# Batch script - Assign variable in FOR-IF

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a file with this output:

```
ANS8000I Server command: 'ru FailedReport'

  Unnamed[1]
------------
       9

 Unnamed[1]
------------
     110

 Unnamed[1]
------------
     101
```

I need to take those numbers, and assign it to three different variables. I made this script, but I can't make it to work... I always got "0" as result.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /A counter=0
SET /A failed=0
SET /A completed=0
SET /A total=0

for /F "tokens=1 skip=4" %%a in (C:\Users\Desktop\Aux.txt) do (

if "%counter%" EQU 5 (set /A failed=%%a)
if "%counter%" EQU 9 (set /A completed=%%a)
if "%counter%" EQU 13 (set /A total=%%a)

set /A counter+=1

)

echo "Failed: " %failed% >> C:\Users\Desktop\Result.txt
echo "Completed: " %completed% >> C:\Users\Desktop\Result.txt
echo "Total: " %total% >> C:\Users\Desktop\Result.txt
```

Could anyone help me with this? I tried a lot of combinations (variables with !, %, %%), but I still got the same result.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /A counter=0
SET /A failed=0
SET /A completed=0
SET /A total=0

for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (q24152955.txt) do (
 ECHO !counter! %%a
 if !counter! EQU 3 (set /A failed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 9 (set /A completed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 6 (set /A total=%%a)

 set /A counter+=1

)

echo "Failed: " %failed% 
echo "Completed: " %completed%
echo "Total: " %total%

GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q24152955.txt` containing your data for my testing.

In delayedexpansion mode, `%var%` refers to the original value of `var` - before the loop began execution and `!var!` is the dynamic value - as it changes.

`"something"` is never going to be equal to `something` because the quotes are significant. Quoted values are often used in this context in case the value itself is empty or contains special characters (especially spaces) - `""` is a non-empty string.

`for /f` ignores empty lines. I've included a superfluous `echo` command to show which lines the `for` processes. Note that the value of `counter` is thus the sequential number of non-empty lines in the file, not the actual line number. Note also that a line containing just one (or more) spaces is **not** an empty line!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "$count=1"
for /f  "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\Desktop\Aux.txt) do (
 if  !$count!==4 set failed=%%a
 if  !$count!==7 set completed=%%a
 if  !$count!==10 set total=%%a
set /a $count+=1
)

(echo Failed    :  %failed: =%
echo Completed :  %completed: =%
echo Total     :  %total: =%)> C:\Users\Desktop\Result.txt
```